# javascript templating, generating chunks of html

Tags: javascript

Inside my javascript ajax function I'm generating chunks of html as follows:

```
$.each(data.pages, function(k, v) {

    pageData += '<div class="entry activity page-panel event-item">';

    pageData += '<div class="page-panel-inner">';

    pageData += '<h2><a href="'+v.url+'">'+v.title+'</a></h2>';

    pageData += '<span class="date">'+v.date+'</span>';

    pageData += '</div>';

    pageData += '<a href="'+v.url+'"><img src="'+v.image+'" alt="'+v.title+'"></a>';

    pageData += '<div class="page-panel-inner event-item-details">';        
    pageData += '<p><strong>Location: </strong>Whitchurch</p>';
    pageData += '<p><strong>Time: </strong>18.00 - 22.00</p>';
    pageData += '<p><strong>Price: </strong>£31 for 10 weeks</p>';

    pageData += '</div>';
    pageData += '</div>';

});
```

I've read a little about javascript templating but don't understand how I can use templating in this scenario? Are there better ways to generate chunks of html within javascript?

Apologies this is not a problematic question with a correct answer I wasn't sure where else to ask.

Comment: A template mechanism is definitely better than that. Far less messy and error-prone. [Here is a slightly aged page to help you find a template engine.](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Comment: Yes it's the 'messy' element that i find annoying. It's sometimes very hard to read the code especially when these chunks get large. I'll check that out. Ta

Comment: Think i'll have a stab at Handlebars, have you any experience on this?

Comment: I've not used Handlebars; I'm a huge fan of doT.js however. But there are lots of divergent reasons people pick one over another.

Comment: How would i use templating in my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different ways of using template engines, so understand that this is just one. Some systems use a "compilation" step to translate templates into JavaScript, while others are more like interpreters.  I'm only personally familiar with one ([doT](https://github.com/olado/doT)) and it's a little unusual, so I'll basically just make up a pretend system for purposes of this example.

A common trick for some template engines is to stash the template contents in a `<script>` tag. Sounds weird, like we're back where we started from, but in this case it's a `<script>` tag with a "type" that causes the browser to just ignore it as an unknown scripting language. (Note that there's also the HTML5 `<template>` tag, but I haven't had much experience with it and I'm not sure how well it handles fragmentary markup.)

So:

```
<script id=robs-template type="text/html-template">
  <div class="entry activity page-panel event-item">
    <div class="page-panel-inner">
      <h2><a href="{{! it.url }}">{{! it.title }}</a></h2>
      <span class="date">{{! it.date }}</span>
    </div>
    <a href="{{! it.url }}"><img src="{{! it.image }}" title="{{! it.title }}"></a>
    <div class="page-panel-inner event-item-details">
      <p><strong>Location: </strong>Whitchurch</p>
      <p><strong>Time: </strong>18.00 - 22.00</p>
      <p><strong>Price: </strong>£31 for 10 weeks</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Inside the template, the stuff in `{{ }}` clumps represents requests for the template system to drop in content from a parameter object. The idea is that when the template system is invoked, a parameter object will be supplied (somehow; depends on the system).

To fetch that template content in order to "feed" it to a template system, you can just use simple jQuery:

```
var templateCode = $("#robs-template").html();
```

With my made-up template system, you might translate the template into some HTML ready to inject into the page with something like this:

```
var rendered = FakeTemplates(templateCode, { 
  url: "http://whatever",
  title: "Something",
  image: "http://cats.com/small-kitten1.jpg",
  date: "12 Jun 2015"
});
```

Now you've got in the variable "rendered" the merger of the object full of data with the template outline.

Some template engines operate only directly on the DOM, so that might look more like:

```
$("#place-to-put-stuff").fakeTemplates(templateCode, { 
  url: "http://whatever",
  title: "Something",
  image: "http://cats.com/small-kitten1.jpg",
  date: "12 Jun 2015"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, what if it's an array of items?

Comment: @RobMorris different template systems have more complicated constructs to deal with looping, conditional expansion, etc.